# How to put a \ and \n at every line in TCL

Tags: tcl, newline, slash

I am trying to search for every files that matches and at the end of the file, I put \ and \n

Here is my script:

```
foreach aaa $list {
    set alist [glob "hier/hier1/hier2/*.lib"]
    puts $filename [join $alist "\ \\\n"]
}
```

I got the output as below:

```
file1 \
file2 \
file3 \
file4
```

The problem is file4 does not seem to have a \ at the end? I cant easily put another \ in the puts statment because it will give double \. So is there something wrong with my puts statement that it does not put \ at the last line?

```
file1 \\
file2 \\
file3 \\
file4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list `{a b c}` and you `join $list :` you get `a:b:c` with no colon after the last element. That's what is happening here.

You want something like this:

```
# add a space and backslash to each element of alist
set with_continuations [lmap element $alist {string cat $element " " \\}]
# then print joined with newlines
puts $filename [join $with_continuations \n]
```

---

Using foreach instead of lmap:

```
set with_continuations {}
foreach element $alist {
    lappend with_continuations [string cat $element " " \\]
}
```

Comment: An elegant, minimal solution -- nice. Is it possible to also add an explicit iterative solution to your answer? I think it might help others see how `lmap` encloses the loop for this case.